# React hooks - useState() is not re-rendering the UI with the new state updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying out the new React Hooks, and I am a little stuck as the UI is not updating when the local state is updated. Here is my code,

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Post from './Post'
import PostForm from './PostForm';
import axios from 'axios';

function PostsList() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  
  // setting up the local state using useEffect as an alternative to CDM
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('...')
      .then(res => {
        // the resposne is an array of objects
        setPosts(res.data)
      })
  })
  
  const handleSubmit = (data) => {
    // the data I am getting here is an object with an identical format to the objects in the posts array
    axios.post('...', data)
      .then(res => {
        // logging the data to validate its format. works fine so far..
        console.log(res.data);
        // the issue is down here
        setPosts([
          ...posts,
          res.data
        ])
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <PostForm handleSubmit={handleSubmit}  />
      <h3>current posts</h3>
      
      { posts.map(post => (
        <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
      )) }
    </div>
  )
}
```

when I submit the form, the UI flickers for a split second and then renders the current state without the new update, it seems that something is preventing it from re-rendering the new state.
If more code/clarification is needed please leave a comment below. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: actually since you don't pass second argument into `useEffect` it acts as cDM + cDU so it's called on each render. assume it's about race conditions between adding new and loading from server actual list. are you sure for second time you click submit previously added post is not loaded alongside others?

Comment: actually that makes a lot of sense, so I guess the reason it flickers after submitting the form is the time it gets updated by the `handleSubmit()` and since `useEffect()` rerenders the dom, so it renders the old posts coming from the server.. so the question now is how to prevent that from happening, in other words, how to set the local state as we used to do using `cDM()` and prevent `cDU()` from running when the state is updated ?

Comment: Alright I got it, I simply added an empty array right after the closing tag of the callback function passed to the `useEffect()`, this made component renders only one time as opposed to every time the state gets updated. thanks man :)

Comment: np. may you create short answer/accept it with highlighting this thing? it'd be more clear for whoever find this question

Answer (score 5):

alright, problem solved with the helpful hint from @skyboyer,
so what happened initially is, the `useEffect()` acts like `componentDidMount()` & `componentDidUpdate()` at the same time, that means whenever there is an update to the state, the `useEffect()` gets invoked, which means resetting the state with the initial data coming from the server. 
to fix the issue I needed to make the `useEffect()` renders the component only one time when it's created/rendered as opposed to rendering it every time there is an update to the state. and this is done by adding an empty array as a second argument to the `useEffect()` function. as shown below.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('...')
    .then(res => {
      setPosts(res.data)
     })
   }, [])
```

thanks :)