# React.js how to access a parameter in a Router Link URL from a function Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I had access to params from a router URL by using the following:

> `${this.props.match.params.id}`.

is there a way to access the same param from a functional component as opposed to a class component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [withRouter hoc provided by react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) :

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const Component = props => ...

// now you can access props.history|match|location
const ComponentWithRouteProps = withRouter(Component);
```

Comment: I was able to access it, but I get a memory leak warning in the console when I go back to the previous route, and it suggests to `cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function` to fix the issue. I don't really understand why is that, but thanks anyway though!

Comment: can you show us the entire code then ? since it may be located around where you use the useEffect hook ? it sounds to be worth another question on so. I suggest you to update post or create a new react hook related question

Comment: alright, I did solve it by adding an empty array as a second argument to the useEffect() function, I actually posted a similar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495384/react-hooks-usestate-is-not-re-rendering-the-ui-with-the-new-state-updates/54495834#54495834), and the resolution to the above warning is identical to the one in the link although the errors were different. if you still need to see the code let me know and I will post a `codesandbox` link, I just thought it doesn't make sense to repost the question when its already solved. :)

Comment: no that's alright. I am glad that you have solved your problem :)